# Is there a better way to test for an integer in C# than Double.TryParse?

Tags: c#-3.0, methods

Double.TryParse returns a value, and I don't need a value. I need to be able to tell if a string is numeric and just return a bool.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: where did the answer that I marked as ANSWER go?

Comment: It was deleted by the poster probably because it wasn't a complete solution (it only worked for positive integers) and was starting to get downvoted because of the problems with it.

Comment: The value it returns is whether or not the  parsing succeeded. The actual value is obtained using the output parameter. There's no law that says you have to used the output parameter if the parsing is successful

Comment: And if you want an integer, why are you using Double (floating-point) parse?

Answer (score 12):

I would consider *exactly* what you need to determine. "Is numeric" is vaguer than it sounds at first. Consider the following strings, and whether you'd want to consider them numeric:

- "NaN"
- "Nan"
- "Infinity"
- "0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
- "1e5"
- "1e500"
- "1,000"
- "+1"

Using `Double.TryParse` (with an en-GB culture - don't forget about cultural issues!) will give you True, False, True, True (despite it not being representable), True, False. True, True.

If you want to tell whether a later call to `Double.TryParse` would succeed, calling it here will be the most accurate solution. If you're using some other criteria, a regular expression may well be more appropriate. An example of the criteria you might use:

- The can be a + or -, but only in the first character
- There can be a single period at any character. You may want to avoid one at the end - should "1." be valid?
- Other than the above, all characters must be digits

That would disallow all but the fourth and last examples above.

EDIT: I've now noticed the title of the question includes "integer". That pretty much reduces the specification checks to:

- Do you want to allow leading zeroes (e.g. -00012)?
- What is the range?
- Do you only need decimals (instead of hex etc)?
- Do you need to accept thousands separators?
- What's your policy on leading/trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 8):

Well, you *could* use a regular expression, but why not just discard the value from Double.TryParse and move on? I don't think it will be worth the effort trying to duplicate this code.

Comment: +1. That's what I usually do. I added the VB way as an alternative.

Comment: because I'm posting my code on my blog and the last thing I need is some uber-nerd saying "well, why didn't you..." :)

Comment: Dev is all about learning)
So if some uber-nerd comes up just give him the kudos and update the code snippet)

Comment: Note that Double.TryParse will handle things like cultural differences (thousand separators, different decimal separators), exponential values (like 1E+05), etc. If you want to support all that, you really don't have much choice. If you're only interested in integers, then ... Int32.TryParse :)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and then use `Information.IsNumeric().`

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

...

if (Information.IsNumeric("1233434.0"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
}
```

Comment: I was actually considering this but I think I would have to add that extra assembly and that's hefty.

Comment: You mean the extra assembly that's already part of the .NET framework?

Comment: It wouldn't still add to the size of my application?

Answer (score 1):

How about a regular expression?

```
string s = "13.2";
bool bIsDecimal = Regex.IsMatch("^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$");
```

should test whether it is a decimal value.  What it won't tell you is whether it is a valid decimal, as in, will the number fit in the range of a decimal.

Comment: Neither will it detect if non-English separators are used.

Comment: You probably won't be able to cover all international variations of a numeric representation with a single regex, though :-(

Answer (score 1):

I just fired up Visual Studio Express (both 2005 and 2008). The Intellisense says that the return value of Double.TryParse() is a bool. The following worked for me under limited testing...

```
double res; // you must be under very resource-constrained 
            // conditions if you can't just declare a double
            // and forget about it

if (Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out res)) {
    label1.Text = "it's a number";
} else {
    label1.Text = "not a number";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this isnumeric:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(object Expression)
```

{

```
  bool isNum;

  double retNum;

  isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum );

  return isNum;
```

}